# Check presence of vowels in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I need to check whether a vowel is present in a word. If it is, an operation should be carried out on the word say `op(word)`. I want to avoid a for loop because I thought of this:

```
for char in word:
    if char in 'aeiou':
#confused here...
```

Please, recommend a method that is low in cost when it comes to execution time. Also, help me correct the above approach too.

Comment: see, hundres of different types of those question are here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+vowels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
if any(char in vowels for char in word):
   ...
```

**Note:** This is better because it short circuits, as soon as it finds the vowel in the word. So, it doesn't have to check all the characters unless there are no vowels in the string.

**Edit:** Ran a [`timeit` test](http://ideone.com/UpHC1r) and found that, [@falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21822226/1903116) is extremely fast, but with few optimizations, the `re` version beats everything else.

```
import re

vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
pattern = re.compile("[AEIOUaeiou]")

def intersection():
    return bool(vowels.intersection("TWYNDYLLYNGS"))

def any_version():
    return any(char in vowels for char in "TWYNDYLLYNGS")

def re_version():
    return bool(pattern.search("TWYNDYLLYNGS"))

def disjoint():
    return vowels.isdisjoint("TWYNDYLLYNGS")

from timeit import timeit

print timeit("intersection()", "from __main__ import intersection, vowels")
print timeit("any_version()", "from __main__ import any_version, vowels")
print timeit("re_version()", "from __main__ import re_version, vowels")
print timeit("disjoint()", "from __main__ import disjoint, vowels")
```

Comment: For me on late 2013 macbookpro with python 3.7 disjoint is slightly faster using your timeit script

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the `for` loop using a [`set intersection`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection)

```
if set('aeiou').intersection(word.lower()):
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`set.isdisjoint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set.isdisjoint) (This method returns as soon as it found match):

```
>>> vowels = set('aeiou') # set('aeiouAEIOU') if you want case-insensitivty
>>> not vowels.isdisjoint('bcd')
False
>>> not vowels.isdisjoint('hello')
True
```

Comment: `not vowels.isdisjoint('WORD')`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Maybe you see old version of the answer. See the comment in the answer.

Comment: or you can do `not vowels.isdisjoint(word.lower())`

Comment: @falsetru +1. Man, this is blazingly fast

Comment: @falsetru I have included the timing test code in my answer and yours run extremely fast.

Comment: @thefourtheye, `re_version` could be faster by pre-compile the pattern.

Comment: @falsetru Amazing man. `re` version beats yours after pre-compiling it.

Comment: @thefourtheye, There's no vowel in the string literal. The advantage of short-circuit is gone ;)

Comment: @falsetru Yup, I took the worst case to compare our solutions... :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, Okay, I got it.

Comment: how do i use the above with an if statement? i want to carry out an operation if vowel is not present so should it go like > if not vowels.disjoint(word) : counts+=1 ??

Comment: @Sword, Yes exactly. Or only thing you do is increasing `counts`: `counts += not vowels.disjoint(word)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def vowelz(a):
        vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
        vowel = False
        for vowell in vowels:
                if vowell in a:
                        vowel = True
        print vowel
vowelz(raw_input("Enter a word:"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex.

```
import re

if re.search('[AEIOU]', word, flags=re.I):
    # contains vowels
else:
    # does not
```

Comment: or `re.search('[aeiou]', word, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do this. It's very simple.

```py
line = input('Enter text: ')
frequency = {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 0}
for i in line:
    if i in 'aeiou':
        frequency[character] = frequency[character] + 1
for vowel in 'aeiou':
    print(vowel + ': ' + str(frequency[vowel]))
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - you are counting the number of vowels in the word and that's fine, but what do you do after to see if a word has vowels?  You don't specify what to do with your counting dictionary to do this final check.  Perhaps you could access the counts and ensure that at least one of the values is non-zero: `if any(frequency.values())`.