# Need to find vowels inside of a word

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

Any help, explanation, tutorial, would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: `'a' in 'asdf'` will return True, that's a start.

Comment: A tutorial about counting vowels and consonants...?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822183/check-presence-of-vowels-in-word-python/21822201#21822201

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
while True: #@ 1
    vowels = 0 #@ 2
    consonants = 0
    word = raw_input(">>Enter a word: ").lower() #@ 3
    if word != "stop": #@ 4
        for letter in word: #@5
            if letter in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
                vowels += 1
            else:
                consonants += 1

        print "Vowels: ", vowels
        print "Consonants: ", consonants
    else: #@ 6
        break
```

Explanation:

@ 1 makes this program loop forever

@ 2 reset the vowels and consonants count to 0

@ 3 User input, the .lower() makes this word lowercase to avoid having 'A' and 'a'.

@ 4 if the word isn't 'stop' it will countinue

@ 5 loops trought each letter in the word and increments the vowerls/consonants if they meet the criteria

@ 6 if the word was 'stop' the program ends.

Comment: Thank you so much, exact thing I was looking for, now Im going to read this over and look at your thought process behind it.

Comment: Just added a explanation.

Comment: Even better, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. But you really should do your homework yourself.

```
 word="homework"
 vowels=['a','e','i','o','u']
 print len([x for x in word if x in vowels]) # number of vowels
 print len([x for x in word if x not in vowels]) # number of consonants
```

We used two interesting features of python: Set operations (x in vowels) and list comprehensions [x for x in ....]. The list comprehensions eliminated those messy explicit loops some other people may have suggested.

Comment: You can also just print `len(word) - vowel_count` for the consonants to save looping over the word twice.

Answer (score -3):

```
def vowelTest():
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    isVowel, isNot = "vowel", "not vowel"
    result = []
    code = input()i
    code = code.lower()
    while code != "stop":
        if len(code):
            for item in code:
                if item in code:
                    result.append((item,isVowel))
                else:
                    result.append((item,isNot))
        print(result)
        code = input()
        code = code.lower()


vowelTest()
```