# How to solve this using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Homework:

> Consider the string 's' which contains the value `Great things never come from comfort zones`.
>
> Determine the no. of vowels present in it, using the `while` loop. Store the number in the variable `count`, and print it.

Code:

```
    s="Great things never come from comfort zones"
    vowels=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    count=0
    while chars in s:
        if chars in vowels:
            count=count+1
```

I know how to solve this using `for` loops, but trying to solve this in `while` loop but getting error.

I think I made some mistakes while incrementing the `while` loop.

Comment: please put your code and answer to the content with the for loop function, it is easier to understand what do you want or need.

Comment: it will help you to deal with your problem [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822183/check-presence-of-vowels-in-word-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Great things never come from comfort zones"
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
count = 0
while len(s) > 0:
    char = s[-1] # assign last character of 's' to 'char' important to do this first
    s = s[:-1] # now remove the last character from 's'
    if char in vowels:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

You need to define a condition which will terminate the while loop. Here we are cutting chars from 's' until it is empty (s = '' or len(s) = 0) and then the while loop will terminate.