# Python 3 // Printing an error if a string contains no vowels

Tags: python, string, function

> Write a function which takes a string argument with no spaces in it, searches for vowels (the letters "a", "e", "i", "o", "u") in the string, replaces them by upper case characters, and prints out the new string with the upper cases as well as returns the new string from the function. You should verify it is a string argument using `isalpha` (so no spaces are allowed!) and return with an error if not (the error message should being with "Error:").
>
> For instance, if the string input is "miscellaneous", then your program will print out and return "mIscEllAnEOUs". **If nothing in the string is a vowel, print "Nothing to convert!" and return `None`.**

This is what I have so far that is working, but I'm having trouble with the part in bold in the assignment.

```
def uppercase(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    error_msg = "Error: not a string."
    nothing_msg = "Nothing to convert!"  
   

    new_word = []
    
    for letter in word:
        
        if word.isalpha():
            if letter in vowels:
                new_word.append(letter.upper())
            
            else:
                new_word.append(letter.lower())
        
        else:
            print(error_msg)
            return None

    new_word = ''.join(new_word)
    return new_word
```

Comment: You could simply add a new variable to track if any letter was a vowel.

Comment: For starters, `if word.isalpha()` should really be `if letter.isalpha()`

Comment: Keep a count which increases only when there is a conversion and if count>0 activate a flag. And this flag can help you decide when to print and when not to print!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check presence of Vowels in word, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822183/check-presence-of-vowels-in-word-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that a string is all letters you can use `str.isalpha`. To check that there are vowels contained, you can use a generator expression within `any` to confirm that at least one of the letters is a vowel. Then lastly you can do the conversion with another generator expression within `join` to uppercase only the vowels, then return a new string.

```
def uppercase(word):
    if not word.isalpha():
        return 'Error'
    if not any(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in word):
        return 'Nothing to convert!'
    return ''.join(letter.upper() if letter in 'aeiou' else letter for letter in word)
```

Examples

```
>>> uppercase('miscellaneous')
'mIscEllAnEOUs'
>>> uppercase('abc123')
'Error'
>>> uppercase('xyz')
'Nothing to convert!'
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot ! However, there's still a line of test that I'm failing (when using the string "HI")

# this should print out "Nothing to convert!"  It returns None, the python term for nothing.

uppercase("HI")
'HI'

Comment: In that case, drop the `.lower()` from the `any` case so you just check if the original word has lower-case vowels, instead of any vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different approach, in addition to what CoryKramer answered, you could use a python `re` module:

```py
import re

def uppercase(word):
    if not word.isalpha():
        return 'Error'
    if not any(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in word.lower()):
        return 'Nothing to convert!'
    return re.sub(r'[aeiou]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), word)
```

I think this is more concise.